# Writing the output of a python command to a file

Tags: python

I am not getting how to write the output of the command "show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes" to the file output.txt............ I tried the below but it doesnt work

```
import subprocess
f=open("output.txt","w")
subprocess.Popen("show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes",stdout=file)
```

But I got the error as

```
File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen("show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes",stdout=file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1238, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The file object that you create with your `open` call is named `f`, so you need `stdout=f` not `stdout=file` I think?

Comment: make an answer @steeldriver or someone will steal upvotes.

Comment: This probably is better off at Stackoverflow. Generic programming questions don't exactly belong here

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question and should be moved to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

The instruction

```
f=open("output.txt","w")
```

creates a file object named `f`; however

```
subprocess.Popen("show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes",stdout=file)
```

tries to write to an object named `file` - which doesn't exist.

Comment: So, this line - 
`subprocess.Popen("show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes", stdout=file)`
should actually be -
`subprocess.Popen("show tunneled-node-mgr tunneled-nodes", stdout=f)`

Comment: i did like what u said but again am getting the same output